# Warning when running spark example on mesos: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am new to spark and recently I deployed my first spark cluster on mesos.

As I am using python to develop application, I tried to run example pi on my cluster. The resulst is shown successfully, but I got the following warnings.

```
16/10/18 17:28:54 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = RemoveExecutor(1,Executor finished with state FINISHED)] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.removeExecutor(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.executorTerminated(MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.mesos.MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.statusUpdate(MesosCoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:495)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postLocalMessage(Dispatcher.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    ... 4 more
```

And also the state of one of the worker is killed.

This is how I submit the application

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master mesos://<MESOS_HOST>:<MESOS_PORT> $SPARK_HOME/examples/src/main/python/pi.py 1000
```

Could anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: After some tries, I found when I ran example only on spark, it worked well. And also there are some warns at the begining which is TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Comment: Finally, I found the problem, it is a bug o spark 2.0.0. When I upgrade to spark 2.0.1, it disappeared